# How should I write a regex to match a string with numbers and some specific word?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the next regex:

```
^\s*(\d+(\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*$
```

which matches the next string:

> "1, 2, 3"

I need to modify it to match the next string(s) with one specific word(ignore case):

> "1, myword, 3"
>
> "myword, 2, 3"
>
> "1, myword, 3, myword"

How can I add additional check group?

Upd: Myword is optional, can repeat several times or be at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Replace both `\d+` with `(?:\d+|myword)`. See [`^\s*((?:\d+|myword)(\s*,\s*(?:\d+|myword))*)?\s*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*((%3f%3a%5cd%2b%7cmyword)(%5cs*%2c%5cs*(%3f%3a%5cd%2b%7cmyword))*)%3f%5cs*%24&i=1%2c+2%2c+3%0d%0a1%2c+myword%2c+3%0d%0amyword%2c+2%2c+3%0d%0a1%2c+myword%2c+3%2c+myword%0d%0a&o=m).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx and look at the count option.  0, might be your count since it is optional.  Not every problem is a regex.  writing a little code may make your intent clearer for the schmuck who comes after you and has to maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace both `\d+` with `(?:\d+|myword)`. Have a look at the [*Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

> If you want to search for the literal text `cat` or `dog`, separate both options with a vertical bar or pipe symbol: `cat|dog`. If you want more options, simply expand the list: `cat|dog|mouse|fish`.

To tell the regex engine we want to only alternate the `\d+` digits and `myword`, we enclose them inside a [*non-capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) used only for grouping purposes here.

See

```
^\s*((?:\d+|myword)(\s*,\s*(?:\d+|myword))*)?\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs%2A((%3F%3A%5Cd%2B%7Cmyword)(%5Cs%2A%2C%5Cs%2A(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B%7Cmyword))%2A)%3F%5Cs%2A%24&i=1%2C%202%2C%203%0D%0A1%2C%20myword%2C%203%0D%0Amyword%2C%202%2C%203%0D%0A1%2C%20myword%2C%203%2C%20myword%0D%0A&o=m).

To match `MyWoRd` case insensitively, use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag when compiling the `Regex` object, or prepend the whole pattern with `(?i)` *inline modifier* (i.e. `(?i)^\s*((?:\d+|myword)(\s*,\s*(?:\d+|myword))*)?\s*$`).

Here is the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/K9wU8N):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputs = new string[] { "1, 2, 3", "1, myword, 3", "1, MyWord, 3" };
        var pat = @"^\s*((?:\d+|myword)(\s*,\s*(?:\d+|myword))*)?\s*$";
        foreach (var s in inputs)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} matched: {1}", s, Regex.IsMatch(s, pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    }

}
```

Comment: and how to make myword check case insensitive? to use 'Myword'?

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag, or prepend the whole pattern with `(?i)`.

Answer (score 1):

To start, your original regex can be simplified down to `^\s*(\d+\s*,\s*)*\d+$`, which, to deal with your desired extension, can be modified to `^\s*((\d+|myword)\s*,\s*)*\(d+|myword)$`.

Comment: what if myword is at the beggining? And if myword is optional?

Comment: `(a|b)` in a regex means to match either `a` or `b` in the same position in the text. So, in this case, `myword` is completely optional, and can appear at the beginning or end or anywhere in between.